# Gaia AS3 Site suddenly breaks

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frameworks, gaia

I built a site several years ago using Gaia("Gaia Framework (AS3) v3.2.6") which has been updated infrequently and functioning well. Suddenly none of the "sub-navs" (galleries) are loading! The client (understandably) is upset and i am at a complete and total loss! nothing has changed for like a year and this is a sudden development. Any ideas/suggestions? (i looked at and validated the .xml, just-in-case)- i am clueless--the site:

Comment: Well something must have changed... Did you try with different versions of flash player? Maybe you are calling the xml without the `www` and some server configuration changed.

Comment: here are 2 examples of many...https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15599355/paintingsThreegallery.xml   and  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15599355/siteNav.xml  thansk f/looking!!

Comment: I tried the site, and from the inspector I can see the images are being called. The URLs of the images are fine too... So I don't think it's an XML problem. Did you try with different FP versions?

Comment: yes, and added this fix (http://loteixeira.github.io/tutorial/2012/12/12/cs6-fp11-json-fix/) for FP11...still the sub-navs dont load..

Comment: Does it work on your local copy using the JSON urls on the site?

Comment: Yes--and i loaded some on my server and it 'appears' to be ok so i'm thinking this is a problem with her server(yahoo) and they won't  'troubleshoot third party--flash--sites'...

Answer (score 0):

1. [Download FlashFireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/flashfirebug/) and install it in Firefox.
2. Open the page in Firefox with FlashFireBug open. In the console you will see the errors that Flash is encountering. Make sure you have FFB running from the point when you open the page or it might not catch the SWF.
3. Fix the problem. Or, if you can't figure out what it means, show us what it says.

p.s. My guess: Improper Flash version targeting. Try re-exporting all the files targeted to Flash Version 9.